# Android SDK Manager, local copy of packages

Tags: android, sdk

On Windows XP, is there a way to:

- Find the packages being downloaded by Android SDK Manager,
- Create backup copies of the packages,

And then later, on a fresh install of Windows XP:

- Install Android SDK Manager,
- Copy the backup copies of the packages to the "correct" location,
- and install the packages?

Comment: You can read through the xml file on the Google site listing the .zip files which the installer downloads and download those yourself.  It's been covered here on SO many times, the usual term is "Android SDK offline install"

Comment: @Chris Stratton: As you say, it appears the best way to get the raw files to by installing the Android SDK Manager, running it, allowing it to update the index of repositories, then viewing the Android SDK Manager log file to create a list of the XML files used to index of repositories, which has the direct links to the zip files. After downloading the zip files, unzip them in the correct directories of any new Android SDK Manager install; mapping for the directories is [roughly explained here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#sdkContents).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using latest Android SDK r18-

The OS wouldn't matter, below steps would work for PC, Mac or Linux also.

1. Download SDK for required platform.
2. Install required packages, like API 8, Google APIs etc.
3. Now after installing required packages you should see these folders in your SDK installation directory.  ( `platforms, extras, add-ons, system-images` )
4. Just copy them to other system (zip first as these have thousands of files) where you need to have the packages installed. (Install SDK r18 beforehand, extract the zip or use .exe, but don't run SDK manager to update)
5. Launch SDK Manager and it should detect the packages.

**Alternatively** copy complete SDK installation folder and copy it to other system, but it would only work on Windows to Windows and Linux to Linux or Mac to Mac.

Comment: +1 Sameer Sharma: Yes, the Android SDK Manager is r18, and the following packages are currently the ones I'm getting: Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform Tools, Android 2.2 API-8 SDK Platform, Android 2.2 API-8 Google APIs. **Problem:** Agree, that there are 1000s of files, and zipping/unzipping the correct directories makes the most sense given it appears you're saying r18 just requires the files to be in place. Problem is that I'm still unable to figure out what the root path to be zipped for each of the packages is. Possible this is obvious, but not seeing them. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Appears the best way to get the raw files to by installing the Android SDK Manager, running it, allowing it to update the index of repositories, then viewing the Android SDK Manager log file to create a list of the XML files used to index of repositories, which has the direct links to the zip files. After downloading the zip files, unzip them in the correct directories of any new Android SDK Manager install; mapping for the directories is [roughly explained here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#sdkContents). Any thoughts on this approach? Thanks!

Comment: Your approach sounds good. But shouldn't you just be able to zip from your local copy anyway, the result would be same, and you should make a single zip for whole SDK if you want, it shouldn't matter as long as the platform is the same. My approach is as following- `Install SDK to path 'E:\Android\AndroidSDK\', update it to latest packages. Make a zip for it. Copy it to another system and extract it to any drive/path 'D:\Android\SDK\'. Now add SDK path to environment variables` and done. :)